# Do time-invariant self-adjoint operators have locally orthogonal eigenfunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue, dirac-delta-distributions

Cross-posting from the Math stackexchange, because I haven't gotten any replies there.

Let $T$ be some self-adjoint, time-invariant (in that it commutes with any shift) operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  Let $u$, $v$ be generalized eigenfunctions of $T$.

Is it true that the product $uv$ must have a local action equivalent to zero if $u$ and $v$ have different eigenvalues?

More formally: $u$ and $v$ may be distributions, so multiplying them is nontrivial.  We follow the procedure outlined [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1778), and work around the problem by forcing convergence through multiplication with some localizing test function $f$, and define the product (where it exists; for details on this see the linked paper) as the function $w$ such that $\widehat{f^2w} = \widehat{fu} \ast \widehat{fv}$ (where $\widehat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$, and $\ast$ denotes convolution).

Here's what I have for a proof sketch:

Consider $(Tu)v$.  From our definition above. we have:

$\widehat{(Tu)vf^2} = \widehat{(Tu)f} \ast \widehat{vf} = (\widehat{T})(\widehat{uf}) \ast \widehat{vf} = \widehat{uf} \ast (\widehat{T})(\widehat{vf}) = \widehat{uf} \ast \widehat{Tvf} = \widehat{u(Tv)f^2}$

From which we conclude that, locally,

$(Tu)v = u(Tv)$.

If $u$, $v$ are generalized eigenfunctions of $T$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_u$ and $\lambda_v$, then we have

$\lambda_u uv = \lambda_v uv$,

and from this we conclude that either $\lambda_u = \lambda_v$ or else $uv = 0$.

I'm not sure if this is correct; could anyone comment?  If it's wrong, it's probably in the step where we migrate $T$ across the convolution.  I think we can do this, since the action of an LTI system ought to be equivalent to multiplying by its Fourier transform?

Comment: Link to crosspost?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4268529/